# Standardization vs Normalization of data

Tags: normalization, standardization

[image]

In the above example I am using 3 methods for distance calculation

1.Calculating distances of actual data

2.Standardizing the data and calculating the distances

3.Using min-max scaler and then calculate the distances

I have 3 combinations(3*3) dimension of data and wanted to caclulate the Euclidian distance for each and every combination.

Consider the combinations 2-1 and 3-2 in this example and choose the best one which has minimum distance

**Case1:Actual Data & Min-Max Scaling**
When distance is calculated on the actual data(No standardization is used) 2-1 gives me the best combination because(0.12<0.27)
Similarly when used Min-Max scaling on the data,then calculating distance gives me the similar result i.e. 2-1 combination as(0.003965<0.018522)

**Case2:Standardization**

In this case the actual data values are standardized based on the mean,so I standardization is done using the formula:x-(mean)/std

Standardization is done by columns and if we calculate distance we get 3-2 combination as the best as(2.78<3.73)

In Case1 and Case2 the combinations which I get are different
Which one should I consider?

**My following questions**

1.The results are changing because my sample is small(Only 3 rows are used)?

2.Is mean influencing the standardized values?

3.Does outliers have an effect on standardization techniques?